# R commands (class, object.size) hang

Tags: r, debugging

I have run into a strange and impossible to reproduce outside of the context of my code problem.  When in browser mode, certain basic R commands just hang.  For instance, class() and object.size() never return, running on objects that should be 1-2 MB in size.  I'm running R 3.6.3 on ubuntu 18.04 from the command line.  Any thoughts on what this might mean?  The code does NOT hang when not run in the browser mode.

Comment: I've never heard of this, rimorob. Can you give a simple reprex demonstrating the setup?

Comment: The setup is really simple.  I have an R6 object that I create, say
```
obj = MyR6Class$new()
res = obj$myFunction()
```
And myFunction looks like
```
...
some code
...
x = private$privateFunction()
browser()
class(x) #or object.size(x)
....
```
In this setup, any operation on x inside the browser fails

Comment: rimorob, comments are bad for code (e.g., no triple-backtick code fences, no newline/indentations), and that is hardly reproducible code. SO questions often don't do well solely on speculation, ergo my request for a reprex: something that is self-contained that we can try on our own console.